# button group into razor syntax

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to know if I can convert my div button group (btn-group) to razor syntax in my asp.net mvc app? I want the razor syntax so I can preselect and pre activate a button label when entering the page. If razor isn't needed, then can someone please show me how to make a button active and selected on the page being entered from my view model data? It seems that without razor I would have to pass my viewmodel data to javascript to perform, but that doesn't seem right. Here is my html

```html
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Listing.SpaceType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                
                <div class="btn-group form-control" data-toggle="buttons" id="SpaceType">
                    <label id="SpaceTypeLabel0" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" autocomplete="off" id="0"> House
                    </label>
                    <label id="SpaceTypeLabel1" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" autocomplete="off" id="1"> Apartment
                    </label>
                    <label id="SpaceTypeLabel2" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" autocomplete="off" id="2"> Studio
                    </label>
                    <label id="SpaceTypeLabel3" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="typeoptions" autocomplete="off" id="3"> Other
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is my model

```
public class Space
{
    public int SpaceId { get; set; }

    public virtual SpaceOverview Overview { get; set; }

    public virtual SpaceDetails Details { get; set; }

    public virtual SpaceListing Listing { get; set; }

    public virtual SpaceAddress Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

and spacelisting is

```
public class SpaceListing
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("SpaceOf")]
    public int SpaceListingId { get; set; }

    public SpaceType SpaceType { get; set; }

    public SpaceLocation SpaceLocation { get; set; }

    public SpaceAccommodation Accommodation { get; set; }

    public Space SpaceOf { get; set; } // one-to-one
}
```

and spacetype is

```
public enum SpaceType
{
    Home,
    Apartment,
    Studio,
    Park,
    Beach,
    Field,
    Backyoard,
    FrontYard,
    Other
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to bind to property `Listing.SpaceType`? And what property holds the options ("House", Apartment" etc.). You need to show the model.

Comment: Can you provide more details , what do you exactly need? do you need to trigger a call when you click on a radio button?

Comment: the model has a value model.Listing.SpaceType that contains an enum index (0-3) I want to set that int to the appropriate label id and then make it active and selected. I know one way to do it is to set a hidden value with the index then have jquery read taht value and set the label to active/inactive/etc. But I was hoping to get a razor syntax way of doing it.

Comment: You can do this easily with razor, but you need to show your model(s) in order to get an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you creating a group of radio buttons with `name="typeoptions"` which have no relationship to the model, and your not even giving the radio buttons a value attribute so nothing would post back anyway.

The syntax should be

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Listing.SpaceType, "House", new { id = "House" })
@Html.Label("House")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Listing.SpaceType, "Apartment", new { id = "Apartment" })
@Html.Label("Apartment")
...
```

To make this easier, you can create an extension method

```
public static class RadioButtonHelper
{
  public static MvcHtmlString EnumRadioButtonListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
  {
    ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
    string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    Type type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(metaData.ModelType);
    if (type == null || !type.IsEnum)
    {
      throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("The property {0} is not an enum", name));
    }
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Enum item in Enum.GetValues(type))
    {
      string id = string.Format("{0}_{1}", metaData.PropertyName, item);
      StringBuilder innerHtml = new StringBuilder();
      innerHtml.Append(helper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item, new { id = id }));
      innerHtml.Append(helper.Label(id, item.ToDescription()));
      TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");
      div.AddCssClass("radiobutton");
      div.InnerHtml = innerHtml.ToString();
      html.Append(div.ToString());
    }
    TagBuilder container = new TagBuilder("div");
    container.AddCssClass("radiobutton-container");
    container.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(container.ToString());
  }
}
```

Note, this uses the following extension method

```
public static string ToDescription(this Enum value)
{
  FieldInfo field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
  DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
  if (attributes.Length > 0)
  {
    return attributes[0].Description;
  }
  return value.ToString();
}
```

which allows you to decorate the enum values with a 'friendly' name

```
public enum SpaceType
{
  Home,
  [Description("2 bed apartment")]
  Apartment,
  ....
}
```

and in the view

```
@Html.EnumRadioButtonListFor(m => m.Listing.SpaceType)
```